# Alter domain change type

Tags: postgresql, types, constraints, alter-table

Is there anyway to alter the domain type and change the type to a new type? I have a column using the domain that has a `VARCHAR(25)` type and would like to increase the length to 150.

Comment: You may ask this on http://DBA.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. And unless you really have to - you shouldn't (see warning below).

What you want to do is:

1. Rename the existing domain

```
ALTER DOMAIN domain_name RENAME TO doman_name_depricated;
```

2. Create a new domain with same name as the previous one, holding the new constraints

```
CREATE DOMAIN doman_name AS VARCHAR(150);
```

3. Alter the type for all columns that use this domain.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DATA TYPE domain_name;
```

**Warning** - this is only possible since we are broadening the domain so that every value is still valid. If you wanted, for example, to make the value shorter you are facing a risk of having values in your tables becoming invalid. In that case you need some migrating script to fix this values before

Answer (score 2):

Create a new domain, alter all tables with new domain and drop old domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, but you could sort of make it possible.

As things stands you're aliasing varchar(25) as your domain.

varchar(25), varchar(50), varchar and text are all stored the same way in Postgres. The only difference is the length check, which adds overhead on the first two.

Now, you cannot alter a domain's type, but you can alter its constraints -- and better yet, placing the constraints on domains is one of those "tricks" that allow to alter them without requiring a table rewrite.

1. create a new domain, say short_string, which is an alias for varchar with a *check* constraint
2. alter applicable table columns and set their type to this new domain

That way, if you've second thoughts and decide to change the max length to 40 or 60 or back to 25, you'll be able to do so without table rewrites.

Comment: Where can we find this constraint? In my domain I have check constraint but I can't find the implicit size constraint created by using varchar(x)

Comment: @AmitGoldstein: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html and you can then see the checks by looking at the domain's definition (`\d` works if memory serves me well).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to

1. take the database offline,
2. dump the schema as text,
3. edit the text, changing the type of the domain to
   varchar(150),
4. then finally reload the schema from
   text.

That's just a sketch. Practice in a sandbox before you try this on your real database.